# How to get expanded sidebar with vue.js and show the page path without collapsed it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sidebar

I have created a Vue.js front-end system and used a template for it. The system includes layout and page header components, which I have imported into all my pages. Additionally, there is a side menu with dropdown options. When I click on a dropdown option, it collapses and does not expand to show the path of that page. It resets to the original form of the side menu, although it displays the correct page. I want it to remain expanded. How can I achieve this?

1. Expanded Level
2. onRouteChange

Comment: Please show your code.